# how to move circle using plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'd like to draw a circle and move it in Matlab plot figure. 
I'm using

```
 viscircles([8.1, 8.5], 1);
```

to draw circles. How do I call this again to draw a new circle and delete the original circle? Also is there a way I can use

```
drawnow
```

function to do this?

Comment: Do you need to use `viscircles` or is it okay to draw a circle in a different way?

Comment: Yes, but viscircles would be preferrable if it's possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of removing and redrawing, just move the circle by introducing some constant in the X and Y data.

```
%%%%Borrowing some code from irreducible's answer%%%%
xc=1; yc=2; r=3;
th = 0:pi/50:2*pi;
x = r * cos(th) + xc;
y = r * sin(th) + yc;
h = plot(x, y);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
axis([-20 20 -20 20]); %Fixing axis limits 
for k=1:20       %A loop to visualise new shifted circles
    h.XData = x + randi([-10 10],1);   %Adding a constant in the x data
    h.YData = y + randi([-10 10],1);   %Adding a constant in the y data
    pause(0.5);  %Pausing for some time just for convenient visualisation
end
```

Comment: this seems to work well, but how does plot know to draw the circle when we are not calling plot or drawnow?

Comment: The main point is to draw the circle (line 6) only once and then shift the x and y-coordinates. There is no redrawing/replotting. You can replace `pause` with `drawnow`.  I used `pause` to visualise the changes with more delay

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to create your own circle function which returns the plot handle:

```
function h = my_circle(xc,yc,r)
% xc x-center of circle
% yc y-center of circle
% r radius

th = 0:pi/50:2*pi;
x = r * cos(th) + xc;
y = r * sin(th) + yc;
hold on
h = plot(x, y);
hold off;
```

Once having this you can plot your circle

```
h = my_circle(1,2,3);
```

and delete it if you dont need it anymore:

```
delete(h)
```

Afterwards you can plot a new one:

```
h2 = my_circle(1,2,4);
```

Comment: thank you. this seems to move the circle. But do you by any chance know how to fix a plot so that i can see the circle moving? Right now the graph scales with the circle so I can't quite tell if the circle is moving or not.

Comment: you can fix the axis before the  first calls: e.g: 'figure(1);axis([-10 10 -10 10]); h = my_circle(2,1,4); ... `